# How to convert url with params from htaccess to ngnix?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

We try to convert the following htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=[^&]+&?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R=301,L]
```

to nginx:

```
if ($args ~* "^c=[^&]+&?(.*)"){
    set $rule_0 1;
    set $bref_0_0 $1;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/ /$uri${bref_0_0} permanent;
}
```

but that causes an endless forwarding :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manipulate query arguments this way. Instead you can reassign `$args` variable with a new value:

```
if ($args ~* "^c=[^&]+&?(.*)") {
    set $args $1;
}
```

This will remove `c` query argument from request (but only if it is the first query argument). If you need to remove that argument regardless of its position in the query string, you can use more complex regex:

```
if ($args ~* (.*)(^|&)c=[^&]*(\2|$)&?(.*)) {
    set $args $1$3$4;
}
```

**Update**

Above configuration(s) won't do the redirect, but only strip `c` query argument from the query string. To do the redirect, use

```
if ($args ~* "^c=[^&]+&?(.*)") {
    set $args $1;
    return 301 $uri$is_args$args;
}
```

or

```
if ($args ~* (.*)(^|&)c=[^&]*(\2|$)&?(.*)) {
    set $args $1$3$4;
    return 301 $uri$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The complete c-param should be removed/ redirected.

from: `http://example.com/path/?c=2460`
to: `http://example.com/path/`

Comment: I forgot about redirect :) See the update.